# Creating script for system restore

Tags: windows, powershell

I've used PowerShell before and understand how it works but do not understand the formatting enough to create my own script.

I am trying to create a script that would in a sense query windows and depending on the response a certain action would occur. If then else correct?

Here is what I am trying to do:

running the command `get-computerRestorePoint` gives you an output of system restore backups that you have. If you do not have system restore configured you will receive a null output. what should I start the script with? something like

```
If ($get-computerRestorepoint = null) {exit}
If ($get-computerRestorePoint = ) {run script.ps1}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the specific question you're asking. If we remove *Powershell* (which you've already said in the tags), it leaves *Beginner in*, which communicates nothing. Your title should explain the problem you're having or question you're asking us to answer in a manner that will be meaningful to future users who see it in a search result. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Variables in PowerShell begin with `$` like `$myVariable = 5`. Cmdlets/functions are called without decoration, so `Get-ComputerRestorePoint` is how you would call that, with no `$`.

`=` is for assignment, but not for testing equivalence.

PowerShell uses operators similar to bash; they begin with a `-`:

- `-eq` (for equals)
- `-lt` (for less than)
- `-gt` (for greater than)

etc.

null is specified as a special variable name: `$null`

To execute a script, you can use an ampersand `&`, so your edited code block would look something like this:

```psh
If (Get-ComputerRestorepoint -eq $null) {
    exit
}
If (Get-ComputerRestorePoint) {
    & script.ps1
}
```

To make it a bit more concise:

```psh
If (Get-ComputerRestorePoint) {
    & script.ps1
} else {
    exit
}
```

And really you could leave out the else if that's at the end of this script.